# Null is getting persisted into the DB for dateTime parameter

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I have a json which i am parsing to save the data into database.

Sample Json:-

```
{
        "uuid":"1111170905035334",
        "serviceName":"service1",
        "timeStamp":"2017-12-12 23:12:54",
        "isActive":"Y"
}
```

Now i want to persist this data into the Service Table.

Service.java

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATETIME_STAMP")
private java.util.Calendar dateTimeStamp; 

public ServiceHealth(String serviceName, char isActive, String DatetimeStamp) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.dateTimeStamp=dateTimeStamp;
    }
```

**Data class:-**

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();

java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
System.out.println("Date Time is "+currentTime);
ServiceHealth serviceHealth = new ServiceHealth("", "",currentTime);
```

The value for `currentTime` is getting saved as `null`. Can anyone please look and tell me where I'm doing wrong.

I am getting binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null] in the console. I have used spring boot with postGres

I am using a JpaRepository to persist the data into the DB.

Comment: You expect us to guess the constructor implementation of `ServiceHealth`?

Comment: @M.Deinum : I am using the JpaRepository to save the data into DB.

Comment: Regardless you are doing `new ServiceHealt` passing in a `String` which should be persisted as a `Calendar`... So apparently you are doing something in your constructor (or not which would explain the `null`).

Comment: Please check now i have add the constructor.

Comment: The code posted won't even compile... You cannot assign a `String` to a `Calendar` field.

Comment: it is compiling fine.

Comment: Because you are assigning a field to itself... `this. dateTimeStamp= dateTimeStamp` is assigning the value of `this.dateTimeStamp` to `this.dateTimeStamp` (which obviously is `null`). You are passing in a parameter named `DateTimeStamp` (notice the `D`) in the constructor. If you change it it will not compile anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Wow

```
this.dateTimeStamp=dateTimeStamp;
```

should be

```
this.dateTimeStamp = DatetimeStamp;
                     ^
```

Check the IDE.

---

```
public ServiceHealth(String serviceName, char isActive, String DatetimeStamp)     {
    this.serviceName = serviceName;
    this.isActive = isActive;
    this.dateTimeStamp = dateTimeStamp;
}
```

Here the fields serviceName and isActive are filled with the parameters of the same name. However the field dateTimeStamp is **not filled** with the paremeter DatetimeStamp. (But with the old field value itself - a noop.) Best would be to rename the parameter name:

```
public ServiceHealth(String serviceName, char isActive, String dateTimeStamp)     {
```

In fact almost every IDE should flag that assignment.

Comment: This dateTimeStamp  is an instance variable . Please check .

Comment: @IftekharKhan added a bit more explanation.